# g++: error trying to exec 'as': execvp: No such file or directory

Tags: g++

In a script this error appears:

```
g++: error trying to exec 'as': execvp: No such file or directory
```

the line that compiles:

```
/usr/bin/g++ -o $PATH/calc/calc $PATH/calc/calc.cpp
```

Edit:

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash

clear

PATH="/media/joris/LinuxDomenai/Cpliuspliusprog"

echo Path yra $PATH

echo Koks filename?
read failas

echo $PATH/$failas/$failas.cpp

echo filename?
read failoname

PATH2="/media/joris/LinuxDomenai/Cpliuspliusprog"
/usr/bin/g++ -o "$PATH2/calc/calc" "$PATH2/calc/calc.cpp"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You should not overwrite `$PATH` in your script.**

Try this and don't forget the double quotes:

```
MY_PATH="/your/path"
/usr/bin/g++ -o "$MY_PATH/calc/calc" "$MY_PATH/calc/calc.cpp"
```

corrected script:

```
#!/bin/bash

clear

path_1="/media/joris/LinuxDomenai/Cpliuspliusprog"

echo "Path yra $path_1"

echo "Koks filename?"
read failas

echo "$path_1/$failas/$failas.cpp"

echo "filename?"
read failoname

path_2="/media/joris/LinuxDomenai/Cpliuspliusprog"
g++ -o "$path_2/calc/calc" "$path_2/calc/calc.cpp"
```

Comment: Didn't do anything, same error.

Comment: Please update your question. Post your complete script.

Comment: I have updated my answer.